# How to refresh page content after POST request without location.reload()

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

**Goal**

After a POST request, I want to update a list. For example, if a user is added, so user list must be refresh.

So I do the post request, then I do a get request to update the content.

There is a way to do it without reload the page?

Thanks for your answer!

**Ajax calls**

```
function rafraichirContenu(url, type) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type
    }).done(function (response) {
         $(document).html(response)
    });
}

postRequest().done(function(response) {
    rafraichirContenu('/emprunts/encours', 'GET');
    ...
});
```

**Get Mapping**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/encours")
public ModelAndView findAllEnCours() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("emprunts", empruntResource.getEmpruntsByStatutEquals(StatutEmprunt.EN_COURS));
    modelAndView.setViewName("webapp/pages/emprunts");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionEmprunts">
    <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table">
                <thead>
                      <tr>
                           <th scope="col">Usager</th>
                           <th scope="col">Exemplaire</th>
                           <th scope="col">Date de rendu</th>
                           <th scope="col">Statut</th>
                       </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                       <th:block th:each="emprunt : ${emprunts}">
                           <tr>
                           <!--/*@thymesVar id="emprunt" type="bibliotheque.model.Emprunt"*/-->
                               <td th:text="${emprunt.getUsager().getMail()}"></td>
                               <td th:text="${emprunt.getExemplaire().getOeuvre().getTitre()}"></td>
                               <td th:text="${emprunt.getDaterendu()}"></td>
                               <td th:text="${emprunt.getStatut()}"></td>
                            </tr>
                       </th:block>
                  </tbody>
             </table>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Console error**

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null

Comment: This is usually done automatically by MVC frameworks.

Comment: @Barmar Oh ... not for me. There is a specific config to do?

Comment: In general, you don't replace the entire `$(document)` when you make an AJAX request. You request specific data, and then just update the HTML of the relevant DIV, TABLE, etc.

Comment: I don't know Spring MVC, but I think you need to read its documentation to find out the proper way to do this. That's the whole point of using an MVC framework, it simplifies it for you.